# Setting up a Django "register" database

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm really confused about how to make a register database in django.

So I set up a model

```
class SignUp(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

THen I have forms.py

```
fname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'First Name','required':True}))
lname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Last Name','required':True}))
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Email','required':True}))
emailConfirm = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Confirm email','required':True}))
password = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Password','required':True}))
datetime = forms.DateTimeInput()
class Meta:
    model=SignUp
    fields=['fname','lname','email','password',]
```

i've copied other people, but im confused as to what everything actually does. and wheree do i put the clean_ function?

Comment: I guess you just got started and saw a ton of things you never seen. That's quite normal, but you shouldn't be panic about "what everything actually does". Just read django tutorial from the beginning, or even read some database design book to build up your knowledge.

Comment: @Shang Wang but what did i do wrong in this example

Comment: You didn't even tell us what problem are you facing, so there's no way that we could visually debug your code. That's not the way to ask questions in SO, you should include what error did you have, or what are you trying to achieve but not showing up, or your don't understand a specific code snippet. The more specific you question is, the faster you can get your answer back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure wha you want to do but this could help, is a register form that create a new user with is_active=False:

```
#forms.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_("First Name"))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_("Last Name"))
    is_active = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, label=_("Active"), widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','email','password1','password2','is_active')

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            user.is_active = self.cleaned_data['is_active']
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user
```

Comment: i'm just asking like what part does what? what decides how the database looks, what is on the website, how is it processed, and where do i include methods for cleaned_data?